# Pancakeswap V3 flash loan, receiving F0 error even though the flash loan has been repaid

Tags: erc-20, pancakeswap, erc-20-approve, flash-loans, flashbots

I'm trying to finish up the callback function for a pancake swap flash loan. Everything is now working however for some reason the flash function fails due to an F0 error (ie. not paid the loan back). However, I can see that the token balance of the contract is transferred back to the pool.

Here is the necessary code:

```
function pancakeV3FlashCallback(
        uint fee0,
        uint fee1,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external {
        require(msg.sender == address(pool), "Not Authorised");

        FlashCallbackData memory decoded = abi.decode(
            data,
            (FlashCallbackData)
        );

        IERC20 baseToken = (fee0 > 0)
            ? IERC20(decoded.baseToken)
            : IERC20(decoded.pivotToken);
        uint256 acquiredAmount = (fee0 > 0) ? decoded.amount0 : decoded.amount1;

        // buy on one exchange route 0 with borrowed base token for pivot token
        acquiredAmount = _place_swap(
            acquiredAmount,
            address(baseToken),
            decoded.pivotToken,
            decoded.dexAddresses[0]
        );

        // sell pivot token on exchange route 1 for base token (hopefully for profit)
        acquiredAmount = _place_swap(
            acquiredAmount,
            decoded.pivotToken,
            address(baseToken),
            decoded.dexAddresses[1]
        );

        // Repay flash loan
        if (fee0 > 0) { // will always end up in this block, for posterity a condition for fee1 > 0 is implemented as well
            TransferHelper.safeApprove(
                decoded.baseToken,
                address(this),
                decoded.amount0 + fee0
            );

            // here I thought that the loan will be repaid here (and it is when I check balances)
// I am using transfer instead of safeTransfer as the function doesn't exist on the IERC20 contracts I imported from openzeppelin 
            bool sent = baseToken.transfer(
                address(pool),
                decoded.amount0 + fee0
            );

            require(sent, "Token transfer failed");

            // swap to native curreny and send to caller
            swapToNativeCurrency(
                decoded.baseToken,
                decoded.dexAddresses[0],
                decoded.caller
            );
            // script fails after function end due to the pool giving an F0 error.
            // this entire function runs up to end here
        } else {
            TransferHelper.safeApprove(
                decoded.pivotToken,
                address(this),
                decoded.amount1 + fee1
            );

            bool sent = IERC20(decoded.pivotToken).transfer(
                address(pool),
                decoded.amount1 + fee1
            );

            require(sent, "Token transfer failed");

            // swap to native currency and send to caller
            swapToNativeCurrency(
                decoded.pivotToken,
                decoded.dexAddresses[0],
                decoded.caller
            );
        }
    }
```

If anyone would be able to help out that would be great!